# List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

can I write this code in one line (Use list comprehension)? I need this to my program. Thank u!

```py
result = []
for index in range(len(arr) - 1, -1, -1):
    counter[np.where(unique == arr[index])] += 1
    result.extend([sum(counter[np.where(unique < arr[index])])])
```

Comment: FYI `list.extend([value])` is the same as `list.append(value)`

Comment: Yes, i know, but i read that extend is fastest than append.

Comment: @Szymon83 you read incorrectly.

Comment: Only if you already have a list that you're concatenating. It's faster than appending in a loop.

Comment: @Szymon83 in fact, `.extend([x])` is certainly (slightly) slower than `.append(x)`

Comment: In any case, have you tried anything at all? Do you know how list comprehensions work? What exactly is the problem here? Note, this code has a side-effect (aside from creating the resulting list), it increments a counter, `counter[np.where(unique == arr[index])] += 1`. Code with side-effects shouldn't be list comprehensions

Comment: @Szymon83 .extend is faster, but only if you append a large amount of items using an append loop.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner to be 100% clear, it is not algorithmically faster, it's just optimized for certain common cases (extending a list with another built-in sequence) but both algorithms would still be amortized O(N)

Answer (score 2):

Move the body of the loop to a separate function that updates the counter and returns the sum. Then you can call that in the list comprehension.

```
def update_and_sum(arr, counter, index):
    counter[np.where(unique == arr[index])] += 1
    return sum(counter[np.where(unique < arr[index])])

result = [update_and_sum(arr, counter, i) for i in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: you *can* do this, but I think this is really bad style